# Align Text of different size in row to bottom

Tags: dart, flutter

I have a row where the children are 2 Texts. The first is fontsize 20 and the second is size 13. I'm trying to align both to bottom but so far no luck. It's like the first large one gets some additional padding.
Any good hints on how to align the two Text?

Comment: Can you upload a picture of your current behavior and the expected one ?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I think you need to play around with the `crossAxisAlignment` and `textBaseline` properties of your `Row` widget.

Try something like this:

```
Row(
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.baseline,
    textBaseline: TextBaseline.alphabetic,
    children: <Widget>[
      Text("foo", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20)),
      Text("bar", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 13)),
    ],
),
```

Comment: Thanks! didn't try that specific combination :)

Comment: Hello Jordan. Care to check my issue here please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62171872/textbaselines-alphabetic-and-ideographic-enums-do-not-work-in-flutter